# Making the text in input fields blurred out

Tags: jquery, css

I'm wondering if this is possible or not. I have a timeout plugin in place so that if my user walks away form the computer a warning message comes down and then they can click anywhere to continue.

My issue is when the warning screen comes down the information that have entered in the input fields on the background page need to be obscured so if someone looks at the screen they wont be able to see what has been typed in.

I was thinking about blurring the info in the input fields using either css or jQuery. I have looked around the interwebs to see if anyone else has done this, but all I could find were blurring the edges of input fields.

Any help would be great!

Comment: I think a modal dialog would be the normal pattern for this.

Comment: @j08691 To blur all the inputs on the page? I have the warning and that works...I'm now just worried about the rest of the page.

Comment: I think it would be better to change the `color` of the `input` to `transparent` and then on click, change them back!

Comment: The modal dialog would be used to display your warning while at the same time covering/obscuring everything behind it.

Comment: @j08691 I already have a modal window coming up...it's not big enough to cover the whole page though and I dont want to make it any bigger

Comment: http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-gaussian-blur.html

Comment: See http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message for a rough example of what I'm talking about. See how the background can't be clicked when the modal is active? You can also change the opacity so you couldn't read what was there.

Comment: @AminJafari Good idea! I will be trying that now!

Comment: @j08691, I am already using a bootstrap modal and I have an opacity. I was looking for something for the inputs specifically as an added security measure.

Comment: As you tagged as jQuery: `$(":input:not(button)").css({ color: "#fff", "background-color": "#fff" })` http://jsfiddle.net/a0r2xqw8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you go, the idea I mentioned in the comments: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c9kddjbq/)**

```
var time=function(){
    $('input').css('color','transparent');
    $('p').html('click anywhere');
}
setTimeout(time,5000);
$(document).click(function(){
    $('input').css('color','black');
    $('p').html('Wait for 5 seconds');
    setTimeout(time,5000);
});
```

Comment: This is an awesome idea! Thank you so much! It's so simple, but so effective!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can hide the fileds.

Like `$(.filled).hide()`

Comment: I don't necessarily want to hide my fields, just whats in them.

Answer (score 0):

Applying css3 blur filter to the input element like:

```
input,textarea{
   filter: blur(1px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
}
```

but it is not cross browser
[image]
 will give you this result:

Comment: That's only for webkit though and will apply it to the whole page if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
body input,body textarea{box-shadow:0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2) !important;border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.05) !important;resize:none !important;opacity:.5 !important;}
body input,body input[type="file"],body input[type="checkbox"],body input[type="radio"],
body textarea{opacity:.4 !important;background:transparent none !important;color:transparent;text-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}

<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>form elements</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>textbox <input value="textbox" /></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>textbox <textarea>textarea</textarea></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>upload <input type="file" /></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button>button</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label><input type="checkbox" /><span>checkbox</span></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label><input type="radio" /><span>radio button</span></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <select>
                    <option>selectbox</option>
                    <option>selectbox</option>
                    <option>selectbox</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in the comments, you could just set the `color` as the same as the element `background-color`:

```
// Elements to manipulate. Any input, textarea and select,
// ignoring the buttons (for this example).
var els = $(":input:not(button)");
// Store the current color,
var defaultColor = els.first().css("color");
// Store the current background-color.
var bgColor = els.first().css("background-color");

// I'm using a button to hide the elements.
// You'll have your own event to fire this up.
$("#hide").on("click", function () {
    // Set the color of all elements to be the same as their
    // background-color.
    els.css("color", bgColor);
});

// I'm using a button to show back the elements.
// You'll have your own event to fire this up.
$("#show").on("click", function () {
    // Restore the color of all elements to their default.
    els.css("color", defaultColor);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/a0r2xqw8/4/)

[jQuery :input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)